# get_categories order by meta key issue?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to search for a way to order categories by meta value. From what I read, it seems like I can use:

get_categories('child_of=92&hide_empty=false&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date&order=ASC');

However, this does not work at all, the categories are still not in the order I want. I wonder how I can:

1. correct this to make it work
2. print out the sql to see what is really going on inside?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: oops, I didnt notice the site is using the plugin: Category Custom Fields(add unlimited custom fields to any cateogry/taxonomy). I will need to check this in more details then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I must mention that I'm using the module custom category fields, and second of all I'm a complete WP newbie

Anyhow, after learning that this cannot be done by default, I looked into the get_categories functions and finally came up with a solution

```
function category_custom_field_get_terms_orderby( $orderby, $args ){
    if($args['orderby'] == 'category_custom_field' && isset($args['category_custom_field'])) 
        return 'cv.field_value';
    return $orderby;
}

function category_custom_field_get_terms_fields( $selects, $args ){
    if($args['orderby'] == 'category_custom_field' && isset($args['category_custom_field']))
        $selects[] = 'cv.*';
    return $selects;
}

function category_custom_field_terms_clauses($pieces, $taxonomies, $args){
    global $wpdb;
    if($args['orderby'] == 'category_custom_field' && isset($args['category_custom_field']))
        $pieces['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefix" . "ccf_Value cv ON cv.term_id = tt.term_id AND cv.field_name = '".$args['category_custom_field']."'";
    return $pieces;
}    

add_filter('get_terms_orderby', 'category_custom_field_get_terms_orderby',1,2);

add_filter('get_terms_fields', 'category_custom_field_get_terms_fields',1,2);

add_filter('terms_clauses', 'category_custom_field_terms_clauses',1,3);
```

(The code above can be put into the theme functions.php file)

then the code to get categories is:

```
get_categories('child_of=92&hide_empty=false&orderby=category_custom_field&category_custom_field=date&order=DESC');
```

Any correction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Excellent use of filters to merge the extended functionality of the plugin with the defaults. Although I've never used Category Custom Fields myself, everything looks syntactically correct and optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give the get_categories new meta and sort using `usort`.

```
$subcategories = get_categories();

foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
$subcategory->your_meta_key = your_meta_value;
}

foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
blah blah blah
}

function my_cmp($a, $b) {
if ($a->ordering == $b->ordering) {
return 0;
}
return ($a->ordering < $b->ordering) ? -1 : 1;
}


usort($subcategories, "my_cmp");
```