# Wordpress: how to order categories by a custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I have to display categories with a custom order using a custom field called `order` (that I filled with sequential numbers).

The code that I'm using to display categories:

```
$args=array(
    'include' => array(22,4,21,23), //category IDs to display
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // => doesn't work
    'meta_key' => 'order', // => doesn't work
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );                      


foreach (get_categories($args) as $cat) : 
...
...
```

Some solutions? thanks

Comment: try 'order by' => 'order'

Comment: doesn't work. I think `get_categories` hasn't `meta_key` argument

Comment: This question looks familiar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350870/get-categories-order-by-meta-key-issue

Comment: yes, i saw it but it's for "custom category fields" plugin. I use Advanced custom fields, therefore that doesn't work for me. instead the second answer is more focused on my question. thanks